# Where can one go to find caselaw of US federal criminal statutes?

Tags: legal-research, case-law

I'm interested in a website or other starting point where I can see an index of all the high level prosecutions undertaken under USC XX s.s. YYYY over the course of the given law's history on the books.

Does anyone have any advice? I'm a lay intellectual researching various laws for personal reasons.

Comment: Try seeing if there is a publicly law library in your area. Ask one of the librarians to show you how to use west law. For more casual applications you could google the laws and append it with circuit court of appeals or Supreme Court

Comment: http://law.justia.com/cases/